# How do I animate a bird to move to the bottom right corner in Khan

Tags: javascript

I need to animate this bird in Khanacademy to flap and move towards the bottom right of the screen from the center.

var bird = {
        xPosition:200,
        yPosition:200,
        flapUp: false,
        delayCounter : 0
    };

```
var fly = function( bird ) {
    noFill();
    stroke(0, 0, 0);
    strokeWeight(2);

    if (bird.flapUp) {
        //draw the bird with the wings flapped up
        arc(bird.xPosition, bird.yPosition, 30, 17, 180, 322);
        arc(bird.xPosition-32, bird.yPosition, 32, 17, 224, 363);
        //slow down the flapping by having it wait 20 iterations 
        //prior to switching to wings flapping down
        bird.delayCounter++;
        if (bird.delayCounter > 20) {
           //switch the wing position to down
           bird.flapUp = false;
           //restart the delay
           bird.delayCounter = 0;
        }
    } else {
        //draw the bird with the wings flapped down
        arc(bird.xPosition, bird.yPosition, 32, -6, 187, 349);
        arc(bird.xPosition-32, bird.yPosition, 32, -6, 197, 363);
        //slow down the flapping by having it wait 15 iterations 
        //prior to switching to wings flapping up
        bird.delayCounter++;
        if (bird.delayCounter > 15) {
           bird.flapUp = true;
           bird.delayCounter = 0;
        }
   }
};
//animate the flying
draw = function() {
 background(0, 255, 255);
 fly(bird);    
};
```

Comment: What is the result of running your current code?

Comment: A flapping bird in the center of the screen

Comment: How can you modify `fly()` so that it uses `xPosition` and `yPosition` instead of having just fixed values like 180 and 224? Instead of having a blocking loop in fly, can you call it with a parameter for which frame of the animation you want? Then can you loop your call to `fly()` so that you increment `xPosition` and `yPosition` and alternate the wing position?

Answer (score 0):

You need something to change the x and y positions of the bird, like adding this block of code in your bird function or draw function:

```
bird.xPosition++;
bird.yPosition++;
```